# Button Click Affects all Buttons

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery open and close button that reveals text upon click. My opportunity for improvement is that whenever I click a button, the others activate instead of just the one I want. I'm a little new to jQuery. Any help is appreciated. As you can see from the pic, a click on one button opens both when I only want that one clicked to open.

[image: screenshot]

JS:

```
var toggler = $('.js_toggler'),
  box = $('.customer-grid');

toggler.on('click', function(ev) {
ev.preventDefault;

if ( !toggler.data('active') ) {
  // If toggler is not active

  toggler
    .addClass('is-active');

  setTimeout(function() { 
    toggler
      .data('active', '1');
    box.addClass('is-active');
  }, 100);
} else {
  // If toggler is already active

  box.removeClass('is-active');

  toggler
    .removeClass('is-active');

  setTimeout(function() {
    toggler
      .removeData('active');
  }, 100);
}
});
```

HTML/PHP:

```
<section class="procurement">
<p class="date">Period of Perfomrance: <?php echo esc_html( $date ); ?></p>
<p class="title"><?php echo esc_html( $heading ); ?></p>
<button class="toggler js_toggler">+</button>
<p class="date"><?php echo strtoupper( $unqiue_id ); ?></p>

<p class="special">Special Item Numbers:</p>

<div class="customer-grid">
    <section class="number">
        <p class="item"><?php echo esc_html( $special_item_one ); ?></p>
        <p class="value"><?php echo esc_html( $special_item_one_value ); ?></p>
    </section>
```

CSS:

```
.customer-grid {
    display: none;

  &.is-active {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the variables `toggler` and `box`, move the selector to the start of the `click` event handler and use `this`, with a relative transversal to get the related `.customer-grid`

```
$('.js_toggler').on('click', function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault;

  var box = $(this).closest("section").find('.customer-grid');

  if (!this.data('active')) {
    // If this is not active

    this.addClass('is-active');

    setTimeout(function() {
      this.data('active', '1');
      box.addClass('is-active');
    }, 100);
  } else {
    // If this is already active

    box.removeClass('is-active');

    this.removeClass('is-active');

    setTimeout(function() {
      this.removeData('active');
    }, 100);
  }
});
```